# Normed space constructed from the iterated double duals of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

If $X$ is a Banach space, and $X^{(n+1)} = (X^{(n)})^*$ where $X^{(0)} = X$, then the sequence $X^{(2n)}$ stabilizes iff $X$ is reflexive.

Consider $\hat{X} = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X^{(2n)}$ where $X^{(2n)}$ is identified as a subspace of $X^{(2n+2)}$ in the norm topology using the standard isometry into the double dual (more concretely, this could be defined as $\hat{X} = X\cup \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \left(X^{(2n+2)}\setminus X^{(2n)}\right)$).

Clearly, $\hat{X}$ is a normed space with $||x|| := ||x||_{2n}$ where $||x||_{2n}$ is the norm of $x\in X^{(2n)}$.

1. Is $\hat{X}$ a Banach space? Does it have a name?
2. Is the completion of $\hat{X}$ reflexive?

I came up with the question myself while wondering about Banach spaces and their duals. Motivation is pure curiosity.

Note: I am working in ZFC, which means I include the axiom of choice.

Comment: Note: without AC it is consistent that $c_0^{**}= l_\infty$ and $l_\infty^{**} = l_\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar I see. All of this is in ZFC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for 2), note that $X$ is a closed subspace of $\overline{\hat{X}}\subseteq(\hat{X})^{**}$, meaning that if the completion of $\hat{X}$ is reflexive, then $X$ is reflexive as its closed subspace. Conversely, if $X$ is reflexive then $\hat{X} = X$ is reflexive.

As for 1), if $X$ is not reflexive then $\hat{X}$ is not a Banach space since it's a countable union of closed subspaces with empty interior, so it's not a Baire space.

Comment: ...it is not Baire unless the union stabilizes.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you, I meant to say that $X$ isn't reflexive.